# AppleScript to add multiple tracks from iTunes into a playlist using a text file as the source

Tags: applescript, itunes, playlist, property-list

I have an iTunes playlist I previously backed up into a text file which is in the following format:

"title","artist","track number","album"

I created a sample file using four of these tracks:

"Ritual","Chick Corea Elektric Band II","9","Paint The World"

"Risk","Deftones","9","Diamond Eyes"

"Risveglio","Goblin","10","Zombi"

"Ritual","Ashes Divide","8","Keep Telling Myself It's Alright"

All the tracks from this playlist are currently in iTunes. I want to add each of these tracks into a playlist using AppleScript. I've been able to do it with a single item (example: title) with the following AppleScript:

```
-- set variables
set srcFile to "/Users/kjesso/Documents/=Scripting=/AppleScript/ipod_gym_playlist_track_names_sample.txt"
set allRecords to paragraphs of (read srcFile as «class utf8»)
set myPlaylist to "Test"
property okflag : false

-- check if iTunes is running
tell application "Finder"
    if (get name of every process) contains "iTunes" then ¬
        set okflag to true
end tell
if okflag then
    -- if iTunes is running then do this
    tell application "iTunes"
        repeat with aRecord in allRecords
            set results to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name is aRecord)
            repeat with aTrack in results
                duplicate aTrack to playlist myPlaylist
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
else
    -- if iTunes is not running do this
    return "Unable to execute because iTunes is not running"
end if
```

However, if a duplicate track title is found from a different artist it will just take the first track since the script can't distinguish between different artists with only the "title" as the content. Do array's exist natively in AppleScript?

I assume this would need to be done with a Property List file? Upon further reading online, trying to create an array to do what I wanted (capture the track title, artist, album, etc.), I came across various threads [like this](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=39129) stating it is better to use a Property List? I'm trying to achieve similar to what was done [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=42286), but instead of sending the output to a CSV file I want to send it to a playlist in iTunes.

I created the following sample property list file if I need to use a property list to achieve my goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>"Ritual"</string>
    <key>artist</key>
    <string>"Chick Corea Elektric Band II"</string>
    <key>album</key>
    <string>"Paint The World"</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>"Risk"</string>
    <key>artist</key>
    <string>"Deftones"</string>
    <key>album</key>
    <string>"Diamond Eyes"</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>"Risveglio"</string>
    <key>artist</key>
    <string>"Goblin"</string>
    <key>album</key>
    <string>"Zombi"</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>"Ritual"</string>
    <key>artist</key>
    <string>"Ashes Divide"</string>
    <key>album</key>
    <string>"Keep Telling Myself It's Alright"</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selection to be not only based on name, but also on Artist, Album... just add that filters like in example bellow.

Also, you may not need to check if iTunes is open or not. When script will run, if iTunes is not launched, the script will launch it directly. So except if you really don't want it to automatically open iTunes, do nothing.

Usually, you do not need to refer to specific playlist "Library". this is the default value.

```
set myPlaylist to "Test"
set {theTitle, theAlbum, theArtist} to {"Ritual", "Paint The World", "Chick Corea Elektric Band II"}

tell application "iTunes"
set myTracks to (tracks whose (name is theTitle) and (album is theAlbum) and (artist is theArtist))
duplicate (item 1 of myTracks) to playlist myPlaylist
end tell
```

I made the assumption that there is only 1 track matching title, album and artist (then I took this first and only item found). If you're not sure it is enough, you can add something else in the filter (year, duration,...).

About the plist or text file or list of records, just keep in mind that the key is that you use same method to write and read your file. So the right question is : how are you writing that file ? (I guess not manually !)

If you're building your file from another script, then it is much easier to save and read records (one record={title,album,artist} ). You will have nothing to do except read and write in your scripts. The only negative point is that you will not be able to read the file with a text editor...but it is required ?

In the example bellow the script read from txt file (same as your example) with 1 track per line and each values separated by ',' :

```
set textFile to choose file "Select your text file"
set myText to (paragraphs of (read textFile))
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}
set myRecords to {}
repeat with aParagraph in myText
set MS to aParagraph as string
if (count of (text items of MS)) is 4 then
    set the end of myRecords to {text item 1 of MS, text item 2 of MS, text item 3 of MS, text item 4 of MS}
else
    -- skipt the record : invalid number of text item !
end if
end repeat
```

The result is a list of myRecords, each record being a list of 4 values {title, artist, trackNo, album}

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, if I understand your answer correctly, the problem with this solution is I would have to put the entire contents of all the tracks into the AppleScript, where currently all the tracks are in a text file or csv file. This solution would be fine if it was only a couple of tracks like in my example, but I actually have a couple hundred, hence my reason for trying to do this via a script. As for the plist file, I created it using a text editor with regular expressions, so it wasn't that hard to put together, but I could of also done it with a script.

Comment: This solution would work great if there was a way to capture the values for "theTitle", "theAlbum", and "theArtist" from the source text or csv file, which brings this back to my original problem.

Comment: I just add the read sample from text file in my first answer.

Comment: Thanks @pbell, I'll analyze your solution tomorrow and see if I repeat what I wanted with it. I wasn't sure if I could do an array, but after seeing this line in your answer "set {theTitle, theAlbum, theArtist} to {"Ritual", "Paint The World", "Chick Corea Elektric Band II"}" it got me thinking about arrays again, so I started searching for examples of AppleScript array's and came across [this post](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-to-access-a-text-array-variable/507#post_2) which helped me find the missing piece to my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution myself using a one-dimensional array (list) with help from [this post](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-to-access-a-text-array-variable/507#post_2). Here is the final result:

```
set srcFile to "/Users/kjesso/Documents/=Scripting=/AppleScript/ipod_mp3s_sample.csv"
set allRecords to paragraphs of (read srcFile as «class utf8»)
set myPlaylist to "Test"

tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with aRecord in allRecords
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
        set arrayVar to text items of aRecord
        set results to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name is (item 1 of arrayVar) and artist is (item 2 of arrayVar) and track number is (item 3 of arrayVar) and album is (item 4 of arrayVar))
        repeat with aTrack in results
            duplicate aTrack to playlist myPlaylist
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

and here is the source file "ipod_mp3s_sample.csv" contents:

```
Ritual,Ashes Divide,8,Keep Telling Myself It's Alright
Ritual,Chick Corea Elektric Band II,9,Paint The World
Risk,Deftones,9,Diamond Eyes
Risveglio,Goblin,10,Zombi
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a script I wrote that takes a CSV file with Track / Artist TAB delimited.
I used it to search my own iTunes library from playlists i've found on Spotify.
I used a online exporter that exports your Spotify playlists to CSV.
I had to clean up the playlists in excel first.

this also creates to separate log files:

1) of the tracks it found
2) the tracks it didn't find
     (i use this list for a separate script that I have that
will then search for those songs on soulSeek for me)

here's the code:

```
-- Choose a file
set CSVstr to "Please locate your CSV file..."
set CSV_File to (choose file with prompt CSVstr) as text
set posixfilepath to (the POSIX path of CSV_File)
set posixfilepathLIST to emptylist(stringtolist(posixfilepath, "/"))
--set thename to item 1 of stringtolist(last item of posixfilepathLIST, ".")
set thename to (ListToString((reverse of (rest of (reverse of (stringtolist(last item of posixfilepathLIST, "."))))), "."))
set posixfilepathLISTCLEANED to reverse of (rest of (reverse of posixfilepathLIST))
set posixfilepathSTRINGCLEANED to ListToString(posixfilepathLISTCLEANED, ":")

--creates log file
set log_file_found to posixfilepathSTRINGCLEANED & ":" & (thename) & "_Matched_in_iTunes.txt"
global log_file_found
ClearLog(log_file_found)
WriteLog("Program Started....")
set log_file_notfound to posixfilepathSTRINGCLEANED & ":" & (thename) & "_NotFound_in_iTunes.txt"
global log_file_notfound
ClearLog(log_file_notfound)
WriteLog2("Program Started....")
property dialog_timeout : 3 -- set the amount of time before dialogs auto-answer.

-- Reading your file to memory
set CSV_Lines to every paragraph of (read file CSV_File from 1)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
set Line_Values to {}
set {tids, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "    "}
set trackCount to (count CSV_Lines)
set foundCount to 0
set NotfoundCount to 0
set gov to 1


tell application "iTunes"
    try
        set opt to (display dialog "Enter Name for Playlist" default answer {thename} default button 2 with title " Spotify Recreate from CSV " with icon 1)
        set newName to (text returned of opt)
        set maxfind to (button returned of opt)
        if newName is "" then error
    on error
        return
    end try

    try
        set newnom to ("_WrangledFrom_" & newName)
        if exists playlist newnom then delete playlist newnom
        set newP to (make new playlist with properties {name:newnom})
        set thePlaylist to view of the front browser window
        set view of front window to newP
        set listOfNames to {}
        set listOfNamesNotFound to {}
    end try
end tell



-- moves through the list one item at a time
repeat with i from 1 to trackCount
    set savedTIDS to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set searchName to text item 1 of item i of CSV_Lines
    set searchArtist to text item 2 of item i of CSV_Lines
    set searchAll to (searchName & " - " & searchArtist) as text
    set searchAll2 to (searchName & " " & searchArtist) as text
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters

    #insert routine here:
    tell application "iTunes"


        --ignoring diacriticals and punctuation
        --set big_list to (every file track whose name contains {searchName} and artist contains {searchArtist})
        --set big_list to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name contains searchName and artist contains searchArtist)
        set big_list to (search library playlist 1 for {searchAll2} only songs)
        --set search_results to (search library playlist 1 for searchAll2)
        --set results to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name contains searchName and artist contains searchArtist)
        --end ignoring

        set foundtracks to (count of items of big_list)
        if (count of items of big_list) is greater than or equal to gov then
            set foundCount to foundCount + 1
            set foundtrackinfo to ("Found " & foundtracks & " For | " & searchAll)
            delay 0.2
            my WriteLog(foundtrackinfo)
            copy foundtrackinfo to the end of listOfNames

            repeat with a in big_list
                duplicate a to newP
            end repeat
        else
            set NotfoundCount to NotfoundCount + 1
            set foundtrackinfo to ("Not Found | " & searchAll) as text
            delay 0.1
            my WriteLog2(foundtrackinfo)
            copy foundtrackinfo to the end of listOfNamesNotFound
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
delay 2
tell application "iTunes"
    set view of front window to newP
end tell
delay 2
try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTunes"
            set frontmost to true
        end tell

        keystroke "a" using {control down, option down, command down}
        delay 1
        keystroke "a" using {option down, command down}
        delay 1
    end tell
end try

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedTIDS
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}

display dialog ("Spotify CSV Wrangle Complete") buttons {"OK"} default button 1
my WriteLog("Program Ended...")
my WriteLog2("Program Ended...")

on WriteLog(text4Log)
    set wri to open for access file log_file_found with write permission
    write (text4Log & return) to wri starting at eof
    close access wri
end WriteLog

on WriteLog2(text4Log)
    set wri to open for access file log_file_notfound with write permission
    write (text4Log & return) to wri starting at eof
    close access wri
end WriteLog2

on ClearLog(clear_log_file)
    set clearLF to open for access file clear_log_file with write permission
    set eof of clearLF to 0
    close access clearLF
end ClearLog (*
    --Progress Bar Subroutine

    --my SetupProgress([[linked-template:text]], 0, "Processing Data...", "Preparing to process.")

    on SetupProgress(SPTotalCount, SPCompletedSteps, SPDescription, SPAdditionalDescription)
        set progress total steps to {SPTotalCount}
        set progress completed steps to {SPCompletedSteps}
        set progress description to {SPDescription}
        set progress additional description to {SPAdditionalDescription}
    end SetupProgress

*)

on emptylist(klist)
    set nlist to {}
    set dataLength to length of klist
    repeat with i from 1 to dataLength
        if item i of klist is not "" then
            set end of nlist to (item i of klist)
        end if
    end repeat
    return nlist
end emptylist

on ListToString(theList, delim)
    set oldelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
    set alist to theList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldelim
    return alist
end ListToString

on stringtolist(theString, delim)
    set oldelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
    set dlist to (every text item of theString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldelim
    return dlist
end stringtolist
```